# Auto Rotate / Landscape Zxing Barcode Scanner PhoneGap 2.5 Plugin iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, phonegap-plugins, zxing, barcode-scanner

I was wondering how to change the barcode scanner to auto rotate or at least landscape mode for the latest version of the Zxing Barcode Scanner plugin for PhoneGap 2.5.

The plugin is available here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945976/zxing-barcode-scanner-phonegap-plugin-ios-landscape-mode?answertab=active#tab-top) instructions on how to switch to landscape, but it's for an old version of PhoneGap and the Zxing Barcode Scanner and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The zxing Barcode Scanner's source code indicates that it's landscape only.

[Edit: on Android, anyway]

[Edit 2: long thread about portrait v landscape:
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178
]