# How can I make the BarcodeScanner plugin works in the landscape mode?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am developing a iOS app using Cordova, and I download the Cordova Barcode Scanner Plugin from this [link](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/).

However, it only works in portrait mode.

I make some changes in CDVBarcodeScanner.mm.

```
#pragma mark CDVBarcodeScannerOrientationDelegate

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{   
    return YES;// NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; // UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((self.orientationDelegate != nil) && [self.orientationDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:)]) {
        return [self.orientationDelegate shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
//    [CATransaction begin];
//    
//    self.processor.previewLayer.orientation = orientation;
//    [self.processor.previewLayer layoutSublayers];
//    self.processor.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
//    
//    [CATransaction commit];
//    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:duration];

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer = self.processor.previewLayer;
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
    }

    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```

I can rotate to the Landscape mode now, but it still only work in the portrait mode.
How can I fix it?

---

According to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945976/zxing-barcode-scanner-phonegap-plugin-ios-landscape-mode?rq=1), I delete **if (result.empty() && hints.getTryHarder() && image->isRotateSupported()) {}** in *zxing-all-in-one.cpp*.

However, it only works in landscape now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On zxing-all-in-one.cpp file,

change

```
if (result.empty() && hints.getTryHarder() && image->isRotateSupported()) {}
```

to

```
if (result.empty()) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the CDVBarcodeScanner.mm. Just replace all ***Portraits with LandscapeLeft/LandscapeRight -> I prefer LandscapeLeft.